# Translating geometry from EPSG:23030 to EPSG:21818, then to lat long, using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, latitude-longitude, st-geometry, colombia

I'm from Colombia, South America. I'm a computer programming student and I have to develop a prototype for a GIS system for my small home town using Postgis >= 2.0 as database back-end.

The local public works office gave me the old Arcgis shape files: one for urban roads, one for rural roads, one for mountain streams, one for lakes, and so on. All shape files contain the *.shp, *.shx and *.dbf files, except the *.proj file.

This is the problem: The local goverment made these shape files long time ago using the EPSG:23030 reference system which locates in [Western Europe](http://epsg.io/23030) (A very bad mistake with they still work and are not interested to change due to time and budget resources).

However, Colombia is located within the EPSG:21818 [Colombia Mainland](http://epsg.io/21818). Using http //epsg.io/, curiously, I figure that coordinates x,y (in meters since EPSG:23030 is UTM) of the roads, streams and lakes correspond to locations in Nigeria, Africa.

You can find a point located on the central park of my home town http //epsg.io/ using these coordinates: (-10153166.72, 1702714.02).

So my question is: How can I use Postgis, for example, using the st_transform function, to translate the imported shape files data from EPSG:23030 to EPSG:21818? How can I "convert" the EPSG:21818 to lat, lon coordinates later? Is it possible to do all this with Postgis?

---

I uploaded the shapefiles (no *.proj available), sql files (with EPSG:23030) and some pictures showing a sample point in UTM: 1106289.573,1131273.240 which I've taken as an example (it's an upper left corner on the central park).

Since, the original shape files didn't have the projection file, I set it in Postgis with this command:

```
SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('viasurb02','geom',23030);
```

When using QGis we can see some rural roads distort due to low  bad quality when capturing the data, so I considered the urban roads layer (viasurb02.shp) for taking the sample point. Huh, That point is located in Benin, Africa.

www.mediafire.com/?s1s6ae8bh8i3kev

---

I've tried the suggestion about importing the shape files by setting the EPSG:23030 SRID:

```
 shp2pgsql -s 23030 -W LATIN1 -D -I viasurb02.shp viasurb02_b | psql -d mycity -U me
```

Then updated the SRID of the table:

```
ALTER TABLE viasurb02 
ALTER COLUMN geom 
TYPE Geometry(MultiLinestring, 21818) 
USING ST_Transform(geom, 21818);
```

However, the traslated geometry is impossible for EPSG:4326 because it is inf/inf [image: The same sample point with EPSG:21818]

Then, I've tried the suggestion assuming that the shapefiles already has the EPSG:21818:

```
shp2pgsql -s 23030 -W LATIN1 -D -I viasurb02.shp viasurb02_b | psql -d mycity -U me
```

And now, the same sample point is located in North Venezuela i58.tinypic.com/2jdny2x.jpg.

I don't know if the local public works office created in the late 1980s, using a bad projection or using Arcgis as it just it were Autocad.

Are there additional steps I can take to make another traslation geometry?

Comment: Can you include in your question a sample coordinate pair from your "EPSG:23030" data? If they're showing up in Nigeria, then the metadata information is incorrect. Could they instead be in whatever UTM zone is appropriate for that area of Colombia?

Comment: Thank you mkennedy. I uploaded the files on UPDATE 2014-07-08 20:16 UTC-5

Comment: I'm just commenting because @paul-ramsey should update his answer as he has the PostGIS info. The data is using EPSG:21897 Bogota 1975 / Colombia Bogota Zone. If you need to convert to WGS84, the tfm is "coordinate frame" dx=221.899 dy=274.136 dz=-397.554 rx=2.808446 ry=-0.448509 rz=-2.810172 s=-2.199943. In ArcGIS the tfm is "Bogota_To_WGS_1984_Region_8_CF". Also, always say where the data is (the city), luckily you'd included the screenshots and I could find out that it was Paipa.

Answer (score 3):

@MKennedy is right, the data are EPSG:21897, so you just need to declare that at load time, and then everything will magically work.

```
shp2pgsql -s 21897 -W LATIN1 -D -I roads.shp roads | psql -d mycity
```

And then see if you can get good geography coordinates out.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(geom,4326)) FROM roads LIMIT 1;
```

Better!

[image: Overlay of roads on basemap]?

If you want to store your data in geographic coordinates, you can reproject them in place using ALTER TABLE:

```
ALTER TABLE roads
  ALTER COLUMN geom
  TYPE Geometry(MultiLinestring,4326)
  USING ST_Transform(geom, 4326)
```

I don't necessarily recommend this, unless you're trying to integrate with a global data set, since now you cannot do useful things like measure distances in meters or areas in meters square without transforming back to a cartesian coordinate system first.

Comment: I followed your suggestions on UPDATE 2014-07-08 21:14 UTC-5. Still no solution. Bad shape files?

Comment: Well, the second attempt came closer at least (right continent). Any other clues as to what projection the originators thought it was?